# changing the focus to next cell using xeed datagrid in c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, xceed

I am new to C sharp programming. I need to make a change in our project. Basically we are using Xeed datagrid, which has 4 columns. Data is bound with the collection object and was updated dynamically with DB call. My question is out of 4 columns, 1 column is editable. when user make a change in this column and hit enter, the focus needs to change to below cell in the same column in the edit mode. Following is the KeyUp event I am writting. After I make change this columna nd hit enter the focus is going to next row, but the edit mode is not going to next cell, but instead stays on the same cell which was eddited.

```
private void _dataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
    _dataGrid.EndEdit();
    int currentRow = _dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
    currentRow++;
    _dataGrid.SelectedIndex = currentRow;
    _dataGrid.Focus() ;
    _dataGrid.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change CurrentItem property. Iam using different grid control so I not guaranty that it will work. But procedure should be something like this:

```
private void _dataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
       _dataGrid.EndEdit();
       int nextIndex = _dataGrid.SelectedIndex + 1;
       //should crash when enter hit after editing last row, so need to check it
       if(nextIndex < _dataGrid.items.Count)
       {
          _dataGrid.SelectedIndex = nextIndex;
          _dataGrid.CurrentItem = _dataGrid.Items[nextIndex];
        }
       _dataGrid.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Reniuz, thanks for prompt reply. I found the solution. I set the currentitem and used the method BringItemIntoView. there was no need for the begin and endedit methods.

Comment: @rahul yes I saw that method was used somewhere :) so if it works ok now - post code as answer and accept it that other users knew solution in future. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution

```
private void _dataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        int rowCount = _dataGrid.Items.Count;
        int currentRow = _dataGrid.SelectedIndex;

        if (rowCount - 1 > currentRow)
            currentRow++;
        else
            currentRow = 0;

        _dataGrid.CurrentItem = _dataGrid.Items[currentRow];
        _dataGrid.BringItemIntoView(_dataGrid.Items[currentRow]);

    }
}
```